# Understanding locking behavior causing deadlock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I'm currently investigating a deadlock issue on a heavily used database but still wasn't able to reproduce it even using concurrent ostress sessions or WHILE 1=1 EXEC StoredProcs. I'd be really glad anyone could shed some light on ways to reproduce it and also help me understand it's behavior.

There are two tables involved and they're partitioned by a hash in a computed column based on the original PK. They were partitioned due to page latch issues on INSERTs in the past.

Thanks to this nice [article](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/06/26/locking-behavior-fks/) (Found it to be easier to do this way when doing several times - don't have to issue SELECTs and DBCC PAGE), while trying to reproduce the scenario, I found out that the INSERT statement acquires the following locks:

1. Obj-IS on tConn
2. Obj-IX on tVarConn
3. Page-IX on page from tVarConn
4. Key-RI_NL to the next %%lockres%% from tVarConn
5. Key-X on the %%lockres%% for the row being INSERTed
6. Page-IS on a page from tConn
7. Key-S on a %%lockres%% for the parent key value from tConn

And the DELETE's:

1. Obj-IX on tVarConn
2. Page-IX on tVarConn
3. Key-X on tVarConn (Several of them with different %%lockres%% since I have multiple rows for the nConn/HashID pair)

Plans:
[Insert Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDuAg.png)
[Delete Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDUgJ.png)

Deadlock graph:

```
deadlock-list
 deadlock victim=process48094508
  process-list
   process id=process48094508 taskpriority=0 logused=428 waitresource=KEY: 10:72057666620227584 (d79f02e56828) waittime=2832 ownerId=28655562221 transactionname=implicit_transaction lasttranstarted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.823 XDES=0x7d33ef970 lockMode=X schedulerid=15 kpid=22212 status=suspended spid=2684 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.857 lastbatchcompleted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.857 clientapp=websphere1 hostname=wsserver1 hostpid=0 loginname=dblogin isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=28655562221 currentdb=10 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128058
    executionStack
     frame procname=MYDB.dbo.pInsVarConn line=14 stmtstart=470 stmtend=690 sqlhandle=0x03000b00a3f2cc6277eb2bc0b8a900000100000000000000
INSERT INTO tVarConn (nConn, iVarConn, rVarConn)   
    VALUES (@nConn, @iVarConn, @rVarConn)     
     frame procname=MYDB.dbo.pPrcInsVarConnao01 line=66 stmtstart=4890 stmtend=5016 sqlhandle=0x03000a004c202f3094703d009e1b00000100000000000000
EXEC dbo.pInsVarConn @nConn, @iVarConn, @rVarConn     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=96 sqlhandle=0x01000a00b3117f0a40e2b01b0f0000000000000000000000
EXEC pPrcInsVarConnao01 @P0,@P1,@P2     
    inputbuf
(@P0 bigint,@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 varchar(8000))EXEC pPrcInsVarConnao01 @P0,@P1,@P2        
   process id=process48153948 taskpriority=0 logused=11224 waitresource=KEY: 10:72057666620227584 (0a7b9247f732) waittime=2832 ownerId=28655563535 transactionname=DELETE lasttranstarted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.857 XDES=0x2760ee83b0 lockMode=X schedulerid=34 kpid=31228 status=suspended spid=2553 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.857 lastbatchcompleted=2020-04-19T09:37:13.263 clientapp=websphere1 hostname=wsserver1 hostpid=0 loginname=dblogin isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=28655563535 currentdb=10 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=MYDB.dbo.pPrcEndConnao02 line=54 stmtstart=2480 stmtend=2666 sqlhandle=0x03000a00d95fa90184eb2b00b8aa00000100000000000000
DELETE FROM dbo.tVarConn WHERE nConn = @IdConnao  AND  HashID = @HashID     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=132 sqlhandle=0x01000a00a7b5550840229a10010d00000000000000000000
exec pPrcEndConnao02 @P0,@P1,@P2,@P3     
     frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
(@P0 bigint,@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 varchar(8000),@P3 varchar(8000))exec pPrcEndConnao02 @P0,@P1,@P2,@P3       
  resource-list
   keylock hobtid=72057666620227584 dbid=10 objectname=MYDB.dbo.tVarConn indexname=PKtVarConn id=lock495af880 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057666620227584
    owner-list
     owner id=process48153948 mode=X
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process48094508 mode=X requestType=wait
   keylock hobtid=72057666620227584 dbid=10 objectname=MYDB.dbo.tVarConn indexname=PKtVarConn id=lock1d7ff99b80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057666620227584
    owner-list
     owner id=process48094508 mode=X
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process48153948 mode=X requestType=wait
```

What am I missing? How can these two get involved in the deadlock above? How can I reproduce it so I can test possible solutions?

Sorry if this got too long or I missed something... First time posting! :)

---

**The environment**

Parent table:

```
Name      Owner    Type          
--------- -------- ------------- 
tConn     dbo      user table    

Column_name    Type        Computed    Length    Prec  Scale Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks     FixedLenNullInSource      Collation
-------------- ----------- ----------- --------- ----- ----- ----------- ---------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------------
nConn          int         no          4         10    0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col1           smallint    no          2         5     0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col2           char        no          23                    no          no                     no                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
Col3           datetime    no          8                     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col4           char        no          20                    no          no                     no                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
Col5           datetime    no          8                     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col6           varchar     no          50                    yes         no                     yes                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
Col7           char        no          1                     no          no                     no                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
Col8           smallint    no          2         5     0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col9           smallint    no          2         5     0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col10          smallint    no          2         5     0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col11          decimal     no          9         10    0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
Col12          decimal     no          5         5     0     yes         (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL
HashID         tinyint     yes         1         3     0     no          (n/a)                  (n/a)                     NULL

Identity    Seed   Increment   Not For Replication
----------- ------ ----------- -------------------
nConn       1      1           0

index_name    index_description                                      index_keys
------------- ------------------------------------------------------ -----------------
Idx1tConn     nonclustered located on schPartConn                    Col2
Idx2tConn     nonclustered located on schPartConn                    Col1, Col4, Col7
PKtConn       clustered, unique, primary key located on schPartConn  HashID, nConn

constraint_type                                                                                                                                    constraint_name                                                                                                                  delete_action update_action status_enabled status_for_replication constraint_keys
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------- -------------- ---------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOREIGN KEY                                                                                                                                        FktAplic01                                                                                                                       No Action     No Action     Enabled        Is_For_Replication     Col1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      REFERENCES MYDB.dbo.tAplic (Col1)
PRIMARY KEY (clustered)                                                                                                                            PKtConn                                                                                                                         (n/a)         (n/a)         (n/a)          (n/a)                  HashID, nConn

Table is referenced by foreign key
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYDB.dbo.tVarConn: FktConn01
```

This is the child table:

```
Name       Owner   Type       
---------- ------- -----------
tVarConn   dbo     user table 

Column_name    Type       Computed    Length   Prec  Scale Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks    FixedLenNullInSource   Collation
-------------- ---------- ----------- -------- ----- ----- ----------- --------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------------
nConn          int        no          4        10    0     no          (n/a)                 (n/a)                  NULL
iVarConn       char       no          20                   no          no                    no                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
rVarConn       varchar    no          8000                 no          no                    no                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
HashID         tinyint    yes         1        3     0     no          (n/a)                 (n/a)                  NULL

index_name      index_description                                        index_keys
--------------- -------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
PKtVarConn      clustered, unique, primary key located on schPartConn    HashID, nConn, iVarConn

constraint_type          constraint_name    delete_action update_action status_enabled status_for_replication constraint_keys
------------------------ ------------------ ------------- ------------- -------------- ---------------------- ----------------
FOREIGN KEY              FktConn01          Cascade       No Action     Enabled        Is_For_Replication     HashID, nConn
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      REFERENCES MYDB.dbo.tConn (HashID, nConn)
PRIMARY KEY (clustered)  PKtVarConn         (n/a)         (n/a)         (n/a)          (n/a)                  HashID, nConn, iVarConn

No foreign keys reference table 'tVarConn', or you do not have permissions on referencing tables.
```

And the stored procs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pInsVarConn]  (
    @nConn int,  
    @iVarConn char(20),  
    @rVarConn varchar(8000)  
)
AS                                         
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON  

    INSERT INTO tVarConn (nConn, iVarConn, rVarConn)   
    VALUES (@nConn, @iVarConn, @rVarConn)  
END  
go


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pPrcInsVarConnao01]  (  
    @nConn int,  
    @iVarConn char(20),  
    @rVarConn varchar(8000)  
)   
AS                                         
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    DECLARE @HashID  tinyint
    SET @HashID =CONVERT([tinyint],abs(@nConn%(72)),(0))  

    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tVarConn WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE nConn = @nConn AND HashID = @HashID AND iVarConn = @iVarConn)  
    BEGIN  
        exec [pUpdtVarConn] @nConn, @iVarConn, @rVarConn
    END      
    ELSE  
    BEGIN  
        exec [pInsVarConn] @nConn, @iVarConn, @rVarConn
    END  
END  
go


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pPrcEndConnao02](  
@IdConnao int,  
@SeqGen char(23),  
@CurrEnd char(50),  
@Valid char(1) = 'N'  
)   
AS  
DECLARE @HashID  tinyint
DECLARE @EndUs    char(50)  
DECLARE @StConnao       char(1)  
DECLARE @RC         smallint  

BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    SET @HashID =CONVERT([tinyint],abs(@IdConnao%(72)),(0))  

    SELECT    
        @EndUs   = Col6,  
        @StConnao      = Col7  
    FROM   
        dbo.tConn WITH(NOLOCK)  
    WHERE   
        nConn  = @IdConnao AND    
        HashID = @HashID AND    
        Col2 = @SeqGen  

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)  
    BEGIN  
        SET @RC = -5014  
    END  
    ELSE  
    BEGIN  
        IF(@stConnao = 'F')  
        BEGIN  
            SET @RC = -5012  
        END          
        ELSE  
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.tConn  
            SET  Col7 = 'F'  
            WHERE nConn = @IdConnao   
                AND  HashID = @HashID 
                AND  Col2 = @SeqGen  

            DELETE FROM dbo.tVarConn WHERE nConn = @IdConnao  AND  HashID = @HashID 
            SET @RC = 0                  
        END                        
    END  

    SELECT @RC AS Ret        
END
```

---

Thanks a bunch!

FT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there were resources being locked in a outer transaction opened by the java app which was disabling the autocommit setting to run several stored procedures and then commit.

This explains the trancount=2.

FT